# Update Set - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I am getting this error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '10'

My code:

```
      string MySQL3 = "Update RegisterDatabase Set ";
      MySQL3 += "uName ='" + Request.Form["uname"]  + "', pName ='" + Request.Form["pname"] + "', idNumber ='" + Request.Form["id"] + "', age =" + Request.Form["age"] + "', pass ='" + Request.Form["pass"] + "', email ='" + Request.Form["email"] + "'";
      MySQL3 += " Where uName ='" + Session["uname"];
      System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand o_command3 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(MySQL3, o_con);
      o_con.Open();
      o_command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
      o_con.Close();
```

BTW I know my code is prone to SQL Injection attack, but this is for my school project so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: "this is for my school project so it doesn't really matter".  Be sure to mention that when you interview for jobs.

Comment: yeah, you're right, but I don't think they'd want me to use parameterized queries, since my teacher didn't teach me parameterized queries.

Comment: @Taabki . . . That's sad.  That should simply be the way the you teach the interface to the database.  There is no reason to teach "string munging" first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
age =" + Request.Form["age"] + "+ "'
```

It should be

```
 age =" + Request.Form["age"] + ", pass =
```

and

```
MySQL3 += " Where uName ='" + Session["uname"];
```

should be

```
MySQL3 += " Where uName ='" + Session["uname"] +"'";
```

Comment: Thank you ! didn't see that comma there

Answer (score 0):

```
 String MySQL3 = "Update RegisterDatabase Set ";
          MySQL3 += "uName ='" + Request.Form["uname"]  + "', pName ='" + Request.Form["pname"] + "', idNumber ='" + Request.Form["id"] + "', age ='" + Request.Form["age"] + "', pass ='" + Request.Form["pass"] + "', email ='" + Request.Form["email"] + "'";
          MySQL3 += " Where uName ='" + Session["uname"];
```

Just try above code.
Hope this will helps.